# What do I do when a PHP library has no Composer package but a weird fork has?

Tags: security, php, github, libraries, composer-php

I wanted to use "phpSyllable". It's on: https://github.com/vanderlee/phpSyllable

So I typed "composer require phpSyllable".

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package phpSyllable.
>
> Did you mean this?
>         cballou/php-syllable

Looking up this "cballou/php-syllable" thing, I get to: https://github.com/cballou/php-syllable

That GitHub project openly admits to being a fork of the first one, but is very outdated (I have compared their changelogs) and nobody uses it. But it apparently has a Composer package...

What should I be doing now? Either I have to do a ton of work to attempt to get the first one to work by downloading the ZIP file, manually putting it somewhere, trying to figure out how to use it without Composer, and then manually maintaining it like this for ever, OR I install the weird fork which will instantly work but has nobody using it and is outdated and thus very sketchy.

To me, that's a "choice" like that between two deadly diseases. What to do now? Why doesn't the "real" library have a Composer package? It even talks about Composer several times in the changelog, making it seem like it has a Composer package... but it doesn't?

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. You received answers in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation at [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/vanderlee/syllable), you can use: `composer require vanderlee/syllable` in terminal, and it should work.

I get the following output in terminal:

```
Using version ^1.5 for vanderlee/syllable
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing vanderlee/syllable (1.5.3): Downloading (100%)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```